# How to determine big O of a variable loop

Tags: algorithms, runtime-analysis, loops

I want to classify the runtime of this function in big O notation. This function is multiplying two whole numbers and checks the in binary digits of the multiplicand. And adding the multiplier to the product a specific number of times if the bit is '1', dependent on the weigth of that bit.

I'm trying to figure out the classifcation of the for-loop. Since the while-loop will go through all bits of the multiplicand the while-loop will probably have a runtime of $O(n)$ whereas $n = \#digits$. The inner loop will execute $2^0, 2^1, 2^2, 2^3, 2^4...=1, 2, 4, 8, 16,...$ if the bit will be a '1'. So in total the for-loop will execute $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}2^i$ steps, in the worst-case (if all bits are ones).

My question is, how do I write this for-loop in big O notation?

```
def mul(multiplier,multiplicand):
    product = 0
    pot = 1                             # power of two
    while (multiplicand > 0):
        q = divtwo(multiplicand)
        q1 = (q + q)
        if (q1 != multiplicand):        # is odd => bit 1
            for i in range(0,pot):
                product = (product + multiplier)
        multiplicand = q
        pot = (pot + pot)
    return product
```

P.S.: I'm not allowed to use "/" or "*". Only "+" and "-".

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Don't you already have the answer, except that you just need to notice that $1, 2, 4, \dots, 2^{n-1}$ is a geometric progression and look up the form of the sum of the first $k$ terms of such a progression to let you rewrite $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}2^i$ in a nicer form?

Comment: And, by the way, you don't "write this for-loop in big O notation", just as you don't "write this car in miles per hour notation".

Comment: Oh. Can't believe how I could not see that. Thanks :)

Comment: Do you now have enough to answer your own question?  If so, feel free to write an answer now!

Comment: Our [reference question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23593/is-there-a-system-behind-the-magic-of-algorithm-analysis) explains in detail how to do this; there are also many examples about [tag:algorithm-analysis+loops]. Hint: proceed inside-out, not outside-in.

Comment: Community votes, please: duplicate?

Comment: Not a duplicate to the reference question in my book, but: There should be _Special case of …_.

Comment: I figured out that $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}2^i = 2^n - 1$. Which let the for-loop run in $O(2^n)$. Hence the whole function runs in $O(2^n)$, because it's the biggest factor. This is just my assumption and no guarantee that this is true. Especially because I don't know if the runtime of "divtwo" must be considered. But the originally question is solved. Thanks!